# React (native) navigation toggle search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

Have been struggling a couple of days now trying to figure out how to toggle a search bar in the react navigation.

My approach has been to

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    title: 'Header Title',
    headerLeft: (
      {navigation.params.state.search ? <searchfield query={text => navigation.setParams(text)} > : <settings>}
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <Icon name="search" size={28} color="#5751D9" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }}
```

[image]

I then wanted to add some logic to the `headerLeft` so it either returns the cog icon button component or an TextInput component (plan to pass the text to `setParams` and use it as a filter in the list component below the header) but I can't seem to figure out how to pass down a state or state handler as props when I'm not navigating to it.. It's the initial screen.

Answer (score 2):

Hook a function to your setParams inside componentDidMount which will
be called on searchedText change, use this function to setState.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({onSearchText: (searchedText) => this.onSearchText(searchedText)});
}
onSearchText(searchedText) {
  //update your list using this searchedText
  this.setState({searchedText})
}
```

Now call the function onSearchText() when searchedText changes,

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    title: 'Header Title',
    headerLeft: (
      {navigation.params.state.search ? <searchfield query={text => onSearchText(text)} > : <settings>}
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
        <Icon name="search" size={28} color="#5751D9" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }}
```

Hope it will help you ...

Comment: This has been my attempt since the beginning but I couldn't get it to re-render. Meanwhile I found a solution at https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/634#issuecomment-302945143